# error while using nrepl-jack-in

Tags: clojure

I am getting the below error whenever I try M-x nrepl-jack-in -

```
error in process sentinel: Could not start nREPL server: /usr/bin/lein: line 260: java: command not found
```

I am able to start the repl without any issues by lein repl or lein2 repl - both work.

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Let me guess, you are launching Emacs from the application launcher? Applications launched this way apparently do not use your .bashrc file. If you do your PATH set up in your ~/.profile file instead it should work. You'll need to log out and in for it to take effect though.

Answer (score 1):

You may have an different environment inside emacs from inside your shell. Is Java installed in the same place as lein? If you type M-x shell, and run java -help there does it work? What about "M-x shell-command java -help"

Comment: thanks for the response. Phil M-x shell and then java -help shows the expected help output. However M-x shell-command ret java -help gives the following message "/bin/bash: java: command not found"

Comment: Ah, so shell-command uses, I think, a login shell, while shell-command doesn't. So, you need to check where your path statements are set up. If you are on a normal unix, then installing Java should just put java somewhere in the path; so I guess you are running windows? Have you set up a .bashrc or just a .bash-login? This stuff is a pain, I am afraid. Trial and error helps.

Comment: Nope I am using Ubuntu, and appreciate your helping through. I have the following in bashrc - 
``` export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk
export MAVEN_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.0.4
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$MAVEN_HOME/bin

Comment: Also I had it working before, I dont know why it stopped working suddenly !